# IGBT C-E waveform

Tags: power-supply, igbt

I am testing a full bridge converter, consisting of four IGBTs. I encountered a strange behaviour, when I load the bridge with an inductive load, in the C-E voltage waveform there is some kind of a drop half way through.

[image]

The gate waveform is correct. When the load is resistive, there is no such a drop, then it is ok. What could be the cause?
There's no frequency dependence on this step. The secondary part of the transformer doesn't influence this behaviour, it occurs even when the primary is removed from the transformer core. The duty cycle is 50%, checked with gate signals, when resistive load is connected the waveform is perfect square.

The waveform shows the voltage across the transistor Q2 (collector-emitter).

[image]

Comment: Smaller the better. Show schematics and point of measure, not clear what are you measuring and how.

Comment: What's the current waveform and where is your schematic?

Comment: I added the schematic, I am measuring CE voltage. I do not have a current waveform at the moment.

Comment: This behavior is only observed when connecting a inductive load right? Otherwise the CE just a square pulse.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only inductive load is problematic. There's no frequency dependence on this step.

Comment: Maybe D1/D2 conduct at that point thus changing the load.

Comment: For this particular picture, is the duty cycle about 0.4, by any chance? As in, if you plot Vg1 vs Vg2, do you get plenty of dead-time in there?

Comment: The secondary part of the transformer doesn't influence this behaviour, it occurs even when the primary is removed from the transformer core. The duty cycle is 50%, checked with gate signals, when resistive load is connected the waveform is perfect square.

Comment: You really should be adding these technical details to question so readers don't have to scroll through comments.